# Neo4j: Cypher over REST get summary of operations

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

Is there any way when using the REST API to get the summary of operations that have completed without returning the nodes.

When using the web admin console after doing an operation I get a summary like

- 1 node inserted
- 2 relationships inserted
- 1 node deleted.

In the examples [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html) I notice there is no example of summary information sent back to the client. I would have to return the nodes inserted to know the insert had occurred.

When doing a request over the network often it is a good idea to minimize the data response size. A quick summary would help with this. is it possible to get one from the REST endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible. It would be a nice addition, though. Have you filed a feature request?